# Automate Xcode Project Creation

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcodebuild

i am fairly new to xcode, i have to create many same identical projects in xcode. Meaning i have already set up my template with files needed in and related frameworks. So instead of everytime creating a new project and choose the template , is it possible to do it by command line ie i run an apple script what i heard so far and in the parameters i set teh project name and this will be created in the desired folder.

I am looking forward if that can be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
 :)

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why so complicated if they are to be identical? Just copy your whole project folder and rename the .xcodeproj to the desired project name.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, but as far i read its much difficult to rename an xcode project, you cannot simply rename the .xcodeproj it wont work.. Thanks :)

Comment: For those searching, Xcode 4 can now rename projects from within the app.